# Why is my C++ MPI code freezing up on me?

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm a noob when it comes to MPI, but this makes no sense. So I have a snip of code here that uses MPI_Recv and MPI_Send, but right after telling me my mesh size, the thing freezers before the first "I made it here." gets sent to the screen.

I don't understand why. There is literally nothing between the first "I made it here" and the last thing outputted to the screen.

Here's the snip of code

```
void initMesh(double* &phi, double &h, double &riptime, 
    double &deltat, int &x, int &y, int &xlength, int &ylength, int &tlength, int &ttasks, int &jtasks, int &itasks, int &tstart, int &jstart, int &istart, int &myrank, int &cores) {
    int tasksize, remains, tremains;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &cores);
        if (myrank == 0) {
        cout << "How large would you like the mesh"
        <<" to be in the x-direction?" << endl;
        cin >> x;
        cout << "How large would you like the mesh"
        << " to be in the y-direction?\n";
        cin >> y;
        cout << "What is the distance between each x/y spot h (equal distance)?\n";
        cin >> h;
        cout << "How much time would you like the program to run for?\n";
        cin >> riptime;
        cout << "What would you like the time-step for the analysis to be?\n";
        cin >> deltat;
        xlength = (int) (x/h);
        ylength = (int) (y/h);
        tlength = (int) (riptime/deltat);
        cout << "Mesh x-points = " << xlength << endl;
        cout << "Mesh y-points = " << ylength << endl;
        cout << "Mesh time points = " << tlength << endl;
        cout << "I made it here!";
        }

//GOOD UP TO HERE!!! Then it freezes when I run the thing with 3 or more processors


        for (int i=1; i < cores; i++) {
            if (myrank==0) {
            cout << "I made it here!";
            MPI_Send(&xlength, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
            else {
            MPI_Recv(&xlength, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            cout << "I made it here!";
            }
        }
        for (int i=1; i < cores; i++) {
            if (myrank==0) {
            MPI_Send(&ylength, 1, MPI_INT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
            else {
            MPI_Recv(&ylength, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            }
        }
        for (int i=1; i < cores; i++) {
            if (myrank==0) {
            MPI_Send(&tlength, 1, MPI_INT, i, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
            else {
            MPI_Recv(&tlength, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            }
        }
    cout << "I made it here!";
```

The above part of the code is where the trouble is now.

Comment: The first `"I made it here!"` is buffered (there is no `std::endl` to flush). What happens if you fix that?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this stuff. What do you mean by std::endl to flush? I did notice that when I had the parts with (int) it said it was dividing by zero after I hid the rest of the code.

Comment: Try to use `cerr` instead of all the `cout`, and put a `<< std::endl;` at the end of the line. This will make sure that your output is not buffered but directly written to the screen. @chrisaycock suspects that the fact that the last line isn't printed is just a matter of buffering, not because the program fails before the line in which the output is generated.

Comment: It displays the "I made it here!" part when I use cerr at least. That's a good trick to know. It now freezes somewhere else. I'll try to clean up the main post to show where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you don't see `"I made it here!"`, because you're missing the `<< endl`.

As for the MPI: in each for loop, rank 0 seems to send something to every other rank. However, *every* other rank expects to receive one message *for each iteration* of the loop. What you want is every rank to receive just one per loop.

Actually, since you're sending the same information to every rank there are two even better alternatives:

- Assuming each rank has the same routine input, compute the `x`-, `y`- and `tlength` redundantly on each process (way faster than communicating it).
- If this is not an option, use `MPI_Broadcast` with rank 0 as a source.

Comment: This helps out a lot thank you. I will try this and see what happens.